# Scrapy ignores custom settins per spider

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

In scrapy 2.0.1 I am trying to set the depth setting per spider. While it does work within global settings, it does not work with individual settings per spider:

```
class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1, 
    }
```

And this middleware:

```
from scrapy import signals
class BidSpiderMiddleware(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # This method is used by Scrapy to create spiders.
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

     def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
```

How can the depth be set on a per spider basis?

Comment: Can you add code of `spider_opened` method? What priority of your `BidSpiderMiddleware`?

Comment: @Georgiy Edited question and added mehtod.

Answer (score 1):

> In scrapy 2.02 I am trying

At this moment the latest available scrapy version is [2.0.1](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#scrapy-2-0-1-2020-03-18).

On a first look your code is Ok and it should work as you expect (settings per spider).

There are several conditions when it will not work:

1. Usage of command line tool with  `-s` args to define settings.

    these settings have [more priority](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/e4750f2fbdacbeb7a20ae7c6b13bba3fb0f7ad54/scrapy/settings/__init__.py#L10-L16) that spider `custom_settings`. As result it will override settings from  spider `custom_settings`.
2. `name = 'test'`.

    Spider `name` attribute should be different/unique for each spider.
3. `custom settings` per spider will work only if it will be hardcoded into spider code as in your example code. It will not work if you will try to.. update them dynamically from spider `__init__` or `from_crawler` methods.

Comment: You are right 2.0.1 ;-) Not sure about point 3. I am using a middleware and have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the error. A few lines further down there was an entry overwriting the settings.

Now I am adding the settings to the existing dictionary and I am out of the woods :-)

```
custom_settings = af.create_image_dir(name)
custom_settings.update({
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 30,
    'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1, 
})
```